# Javascript create a calculator and display the result

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm currently working on a basic calculator project using JavaScript, and I'm encountering an issue with displaying the calculations on the calculator screen.

As a beginner in JavaScript, I've been trying to implement the functionality where clicking on the calculator buttons should display the corresponding calculations on the screen. However, despite my efforts, nothing seems to be appearing on the calculator screen.

I've checked my code and attempted to debug, but as a newcomer to JavaScript, I'm finding it challenging to identify the root cause of the problem.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could take a look at my code and provide guidance on what might be going wrong. I'm open to any suggestions or corrections to my code.

Here's a simplified version of my JavaScript code:

```js
let num1 = null;
let num2 = null;
let operator = null;
let result = null;
const calcBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
const outputNum = document.getElementById('outputNum');

//display the number clicked
const displayValue = () => {
  if (num1 !== null && operator !== null) {
    outputNum.innerHTML = `<p id="outputNum">${num1} ${operator} ${num2 !== null}</p>`
  }
}





//dertermine how calculator will work
const calcul = (num1, num2, operator) => {
  let result;

  switch (num1, num2, operator) {
    case '+':
      result = num1 + num2
      break;
    case '-':
      result = num1 - num2
      break;
    case '*':
      result = num1 * num2
      break;
    case '/':
      result = num1 / num2
      break;
    case '%':
      result = num1 % num2
      break;
  }
  return result;
}

//detect which button is clicked and assign it to a variable
const calculBtn = (e) => {

  const btn = e.target.textContent;

  if (btn >= '0' && btn <= '9') {
    if (num1 === null) {
      num1 = parseInt(btn);
    } else if (operator === null) {
      num1 * 10 + parseInt(btn);
    }
    if (num2 === null) {
      num2 = parseInt(btn);
    } else if (result === null) {
      num2 * 10 + parseInt(btn);

      displayValue();

    } else if (operator === 'C') {
      num1 = null;
      num2 = null;
      operator = null;
      outputNum.innerHTML = '';

    } else if (btn === '=') {
      const result = calcul(num1, num2, operator);
      outputNum.innerHTML = result;

      num1 = result;
      num2 = null;
      operator = null;

    } else {
      operator = btn;
      displayValue();
    }
  }

}




calcBtn.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', calculBtn)
});
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="display">
    <div class="output">
      <p id="outputNum"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="btn clear">C</div>
    <div class="btn operator">%</div>
    <div class="btn operator">/</div>
    <div class="btn operator">x</div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-row">
    <div class="btn ">7</div>
    <div class="btn">8</div>
    <div class="btn">9</div>
    <div class="btn operator">-</div>
  </div>

  <div class="third-row">
    <div class="btn">4</div>
    <div class="btn">5</div>
    <div class="btn">6</div>
    <div class="btn operator">+</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fourth-row">
    <div class="btn">1</div>
    <div class="btn">2</div>
    <div class="btn">3</div>
    <div class="btn result">=</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fifth-row">
    <div class="btn">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A good JSlinter will help you out with the syntax. Will save you the time to post too!

Answer (score 0):

In `calculBtn()`, it seems more intuitive to try to see if the `textContent` is an integer, instead of using greater/less than or equal to operators with strings. So consider instead of:

```js
const btn = e.target.textContent;

if (btn >= '0' && btn <= '9') {
```

Do:

```js
const btn = e.target.textContent;
const maybeInt = parseInt(btn, 10);
if (Number.isInteger(maybeInt)) {
```

Furthermore, again in `calculBtn()`, it seems life the conditional branches are flawed:

```js
// This if limits this code branch to 0-9 only, meaning:
if (Number.isInteger(maybeInt)) {
  if (num1 === null) {
    …
  } else if (operator === null) {
    …
  }
  if (num2 === null) {
    …
  } else if (result === null) {
    // This branch is never visited since the parent conditional `if` branch
    // has already limited this code branch to 0-9 only.
  } else if (operator === 'C') {
    // This is never visited.
  } else if (btn === '=') {
    // This is never visited.
  } else {
    // This is never visited.
  }
}
```

This means the code never visits the later conditional branches as indicated above which means the non-number buttons never do anything, meaning `operator` is never assigned a value. This in turn means that in `displayValue()`:

```js
if (num1 !== null && operator !== null) {
```

This conditional would never evaluate to a truthy value and thus nothing would ever be displayed in the HTML.

Instead, we should have the operator conditionals in `calculBtn()` be branches from the initial `if`, not inside it:

```js
if (Number.isInteger(maybeInt)) {
  …
} else if (operator === 'C') {
  …
} else if (btn === '=') {
  …
} else {
  …
}
```

With all these changes, there will at least be a display once `num1` and `operator` are not `null`:

```js
let num1 = null;
let num2 = null;
let operator = null;
let result = null;
const calcBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const outputNum = document.getElementById("outputNum");

//display the number clicked
const displayValue = () => {
  if (num1 !== null && operator !== null) {
    outputNum.innerHTML = `<p id="outputNum">${num1} ${operator} ${num2 !== null}</p>`;
  }
};

//dertermine how calculator will work
const calcul = (num1, num2, operator) => {
  let result;

  switch ((num1, num2, operator)) {
    case "+":
      result = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case "-":
      result = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case "*":
      result = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case "/":
      result = num1 / num2;
      break;
    case "%":
      result = num1 % num2;
      break;
  }
  return result;
};

//detect which button is clicked and assign it to a variable
const calculBtn = (e) => {
  const btn = e.target.textContent;
  const maybeInt = parseInt(btn, 10);
  if (Number.isInteger(maybeInt)) {
    if (num1 === null) {
      num1 = parseInt(btn);
    } else if (operator === null) {
      num1 * 10 + parseInt(btn);
    }
    if (num2 === null) {
      num2 = parseInt(btn);
    } else if (result === null) {
      num2 * 10 + parseInt(btn);
      displayValue();
    }
  } else if (operator === "C") {
    num1 = null;
    num2 = null;
    operator = null;
    outputNum.innerHTML = "";
  } else if (btn === "=") {
    const result = calcul(num1, num2, operator);
    outputNum.innerHTML = result;

    num1 = result;
    num2 = null;
    operator = null;
  } else {
    operator = btn;
    displayValue();
  }
};

calcBtn.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", calculBtn);
});
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <div class="display">
    <div class="output">
      <p id="outputNum"></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="first-row">
    <div class="btn clear">C</div>
    <div class="btn operator">%</div>
    <div class="btn operator">/</div>
    <div class="btn operator">x</div>
  </div>

  <div class="second-row">
    <div class="btn">7</div>
    <div class="btn">8</div>
    <div class="btn">9</div>
    <div class="btn operator">-</div>
  </div>

  <div class="third-row">
    <div class="btn">4</div>
    <div class="btn">5</div>
    <div class="btn">6</div>
    <div class="btn operator">+</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fourth-row">
    <div class="btn">1</div>
    <div class="btn">2</div>
    <div class="btn">3</div>
    <div class="btn result">=</div>
  </div>

  <div class="fifth-row">
    <div class="btn">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code:

**1.** In the `calculBtn` function, you mixed up the `if` bracket endings - there is one big `if (btn >= '0' && btn <= '9')`, and in it `(operator === 'C')`, `(btn === '=')`, and so on, but it should look more like in the code below.

**2.** In the `calculBtn` function, there should be a `num1 =` before `num1 * 10 + parseInt(btn)` (Without assignment, it is just a useless statement), and the same later with `num2`.

**3.** `else if (operator === 'C')` -> `else if (btn === 'C')`

```js
const calculBtn = (e) => {

    const btn = e.target.textContent;

    if (btn >= '0' && btn <= '9') {
        if (num1 === null) {
            num1 = parseInt(btn);
        } else if (operator === null) {
            num1 = num1 * 10 + parseInt(btn);
        }
        if (num2 === null) {
            num2 = parseInt(btn);
        } else if (result === null) {
            num2 = num2 * 10 + parseInt(btn);

            displayValue();

        }
    } else if (btn === 'C') {
        num1 = null;
        num2 = null;
        operator = null;
        outputNum.innerHTML = '';

    } else if (btn === '=') {
        const result = calcul(num1, num2, operator);
        outputNum.innerHTML = result;

        num1 = result;
        num2 = null;
        operator = null;

    } else {
        operator = btn;
        displayValue();
    }
}
```

After fixing those problems, the text on the top should be displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys for your answers, finally I find out an other solution to the problems and it works perfectly !

```js
let num1 = null;
let num2 = null;
let operator = null;
let result = null;
const calcBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");
const outputNum = document.getElementById("outputNum");
outputNum.innerHTML = "";

//display the number clicked
const displayValue = () => {
    const outputText = (num1 !== null ? num1 : '') + (operator !== null ? ' ' + operator : '') + (num2 !== null ? ' ' + num2 : '');
    outputNum.innerText = outputText;
};

//dertermine how calculator will work
const calcul = (num1, num2, operator) => {
  let result;

  switch ((num1, num2, operator)) {
    case "+":
      result = num1 + num2;
      break;
    case "-":
      result = num1 - num2;
      break;
    case "x":
      result = num1 * num2;
      break;
    case "/":
      result = num1 / num2;
      break;
    case "%":
      result = num1 % num2;
      break;
  }
  return result;
  
};

//detect which button is clicked and assign it to a variable
const calculBtn = (e) => {
    const btn = e.target.textContent;

    if (btn >= '0' && btn <= '9') {
      if (num1 === null) {
        num1 = parseInt(btn);
        
      } else if (operator === null) {
        num1 = num1 * 10 + parseInt(btn);
      } else if (num2 === null) {
        num2 = parseInt(btn);
      } else {
        num2 = num2 * 10 + parseInt(btn);
      }

      displayValue();

    } else if (btn === 'C') {
      num1 = null;
      num2 = null;
      operator = null;
      outputNum.innerHTML = '';
    } else if (btn === '=') {
      if (num1 !== null && num2 !== null && operator !== null) {
        result = calcul(num1, num2, operator);
        outputNum.innerHTML = result;
        num1 = result;
        num2 = null;
        operator = null;
      }
    } else {
      operator = btn;
      displayValue();
    }
};

calcBtn.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", calculBtn);
});
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #040404;
}

.calculator{
    border: solid 1px #4e4a4a;
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin: 150px auto;
    width: 400px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:  1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
}


.display{
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    background-color: #db1a1a;
}

.first-row{ 
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    background-color: #040404;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.first-row, .btn{
 padding: 20px;
 
}

.second-row{
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    background-color: #040404;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.second-row, .btn{
    padding: 20px;
}

.third-row{
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    background-color: #040404;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.third-row, .btn{
    padding: 20px;
}

.fourth-row{
    border-radius: 10px;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    background-color:#040404;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.fourth-row, .btn{
    padding: 20px;
}

.fifth-row{
 margin-left: 158px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn{
    background-color: orange;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    width: 70px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    color: azure;
    border-radius: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #db1a1a;
    color: azure;
}



.output p{
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculatrice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/calcultarice.png" >
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="display">
            <div class="output">
                <p id="outputNum"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="first-row">
            <div class="btn clear">C</div>
            <div class="btn operator">%</div>
            <div class="btn operator">/</div>
            <div class="btn operator">x</div>
        </div>

        <div class="second-row">
            <div class="btn ">7</div>
            <div class="btn">8</div>
            <div class="btn">9</div>
            <div class="btn operator">-</div>
        </div>

        <div class="third-row">
            <div class="btn">4</div>
            <div class="btn">5</div>
            <div class="btn">6</div>
            <div class="btn operator">+</div>
        </div>

        <div class="fourth-row">
            <div class="btn">1</div>
            <div class="btn">2</div>
            <div class="btn">3</div>
            <div class="btn result">=</div>
        </div>

        <div class="fifth-row">
            <div class="btn">0</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```